# How can I show related data in full calendar from multiple tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have asp.net mvc site with full calendar. I also created tables like 'Event' and 'Room'. In my event table i have RoomId field.

This is how my function looks:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var events = [];
        var selectedEvent = null;
        FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
        function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
            events = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/CalendarEvent/GetEvents",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        events.push({
                            eventID: v.Id,
                            title: v.Job,
                            description: v.Description,
                            start: moment(v.Start),
                            end: v.DutyEnd != null ? moment(v.End) : null,
                            room: v.RoomId,                             

                        });
                    })

                    GenerateCalender(events);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            })
        }
```

On this moment, calendar displays Id. How can I refer to another table?

And this is my controller:

```
 public JsonResult GetEvents()
    {
        using (Context dc = new Context())
        {
            dc.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            var events = dc.Event.ToList();
            return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to get data from the 'room' table with the id from the 'event' table?

Comment: Yes. In the 'Event' table, RoomID is foreign key to 'Room' table.

Comment: Sounds like this is a Linq or SQL question, not a fullCalendar question. Please tag it with the area which is actually giving you the problem

Answer (score 0):

You will need to join the event table with the room table. In your controller method `GetEvents()` you can create a select query something along the lines of the following:

`var query = (from event in dc.event
        join rooms in dc.rooms on event.roomId equals rooms.roomId
            select new
            {
                eventID: event.Id,
                title: event.Job,
                description: event.Description,
                roomId: room.RoomId,
                roomName: room.Name
                roomSize: room.Size
            }).ToList();`

Hope this helps.

Comment: it compiles, but I can only display RoomId.. With room name, i have failed alert

Comment: The `roomName` in the query was only an example... Try to remove it and try again.